# Azure / U-SQL - Regex substitution

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have some data containing spaces () and hyphens (`-`) that I'd like to convert to underscore characters (`_`).  In other languages (ie R) I can write something like this:

```
var1 <- gsub(var1, "s+|\\-", "_")
```

which will look for multiple characters and convert them all to some other character.

Is there a way to do this in U-SQL?

EDIT:

I tried this and it ran without error but did not change the data:

```
@t2 = SELECT var1,
           var2,
           var3.Replace("s+|\\'|\\-","_") AS var3          
    FROM @t1;
```

Comment: I think you meant `gsub(var1, "\\s+|-", "_")`. Isn't there any REGEXP_REPLACE function?

Comment: Not sure if it is built in but it looks like you may use .NET `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(src, pattern, repl)` there.

Comment: You could define your own assembly using the CLR. Key points [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230084415/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx). Note: just realized I don't know if it's ok with Azure SQL.

Comment: @PJProudhon u-sql is different from t-sql. U-sql 'belongs' to azure data lake analytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there but you are using the `System.String.Replace` instead of the one for a regular expression. So change

```
@t2 = SELECT var1,
       var2,
       var3.Replace("s+|\\'|\\-","_") AS var3          
FROM @t1;
```

to

```
@t2 = SELECT var1,
       var2,
       Regex.Replace(var3, "s+|\\'|\\-", "_") AS var3          
FROM @t1;
```

Edit: I am not an expert on regular expression so I did not validate the expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@someData =
SELECT * FROM
    ( VALUES
    ("tic tac-toe")
    ) AS T(col1);

DECLARE  @pattern string = "\\s|-";

@result =
SELECT  col1 AS original,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  "\\s",    "_") AS regex_replaceSpace,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  "-",    "_") AS regex_replaceHypen,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  "\\055",    "_") AS regex_replaceHypenDecimal,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  "\\s|-",    "_") AS regex_replaceBoth,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  @"\s|-",    "_") AS regex_replaceBoth_verbatim,
        Regex.Replace(col1,  @pattern,    "_") AS regex_replaceBoth_pattern,

        col1.Replace(" ", "_") AS string_replaceSpace,
        col1.Replace("-", "_") AS string_replaceHypen,
        col1.Replace("-", "_").Replace(" ", "_") AS string_replaceBoth
FROM @someData;

OUTPUT @result
TO "/Replace.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: true);
```